# When casting a spell using Twinned Spell does it use one or two spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-slots, metamagic

Say I cast fireball using Twinned spell, I would expend 3 sorcery points and cast a second fireball, would casting those two fireballs use one or two of my level 3 spell slots?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Using Twinned Spell only uses one spell slot.** This is because you are not casting two spells, rather you are making a single spell hit more than one target.

> "...target a second creature in range with **the same spell**..."

However, it's worth noting that **you can't cast Fireball with Twinned Spell.**

Quote from PHB page 102 (emphasis mine)

> Twinned Spell: When you cast a spell **that targets only one creature** and doesn’t have a range of self, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the spell’s level to target a second creature in range with the same spell (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip).